# How to setup a DotNetCoreCLI@2 task to publish a self-contained exe-file for a WPF project with .Net 8?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

#### The settings

My goal is to understand the CI/CD process on Azure (and in general). For that, I have build a little Wpf-App. It is not doing much. Just displaying a simple ReadMe.txt file.
A test project is included and the tests are running fine.
Also, I am practicing app-configuration by replacing placeholders in appsettings.json by varibles in azure-pipelines.yml. This is running as supposed.

#### The goal to accomplish

Now I am working on publishing a self-contained exe-file that is excluding appsettings.json. That is where I do need some help. **Is this task configured, properly?**

```yml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Publish'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: false
    arguments: '-c $(buildConfiguration) -r $(runtimeId) --self-contained true --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: false
  enabled: true
```

#### References

- [PublishAppsWithCli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli)
- [AzurePipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/?view=azure-devops)
- [TrainingCourse](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLLWMQd6PeGY0bEMxObA6dtYXuJOGfxSPx) (Phase 2; especially Video 50)

[image]

#### The code

The project file:

- the project's `SelfContained` property is set to `true`
- the appsettings.json file `ExcludeFromSingleFile` property is set to `true`
- the appsettings.[Environment].json files are added to gitignore.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <SelfContained>True</SelfContained>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Mvvm" Version="8.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="8.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DevOpsWpf.Library\DevOpsWpf.Library.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="appsettings.Development.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <ExcludeFromSingleFile>True</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
    </None>
    <None Update="appsettings.Production.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="appsettings.Staging.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Documentations\AzureDevOpsSolution.docx">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Documentations\ReadMe.txt">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Properties\launchSettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  
</Project>
```

The azure-pipeline file:

- task VSBuild@1 is currently disabled
- instead task DotNetCoreCLI@2 is enabled

I can not figure out which arguments in DotNetCoreCLI@2 to use to accomplish my goal.

```yml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

# Check replacetokens-task and appsettings.json
# the following variables are used in appsettings.json
# applicationHomeDirectory
# applicationName
variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  runtimeId: 'win-x64'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  applicationHomeDirectory: 'C:\DevOpsSolution'
  applicationName: 'Azur DevOps Solution (azure-pipelines.yml)'

# not sure, if this is needed
steps:
- task: DeleteFiles@1
  displayName: 'Delete files in artifactstagingdirectory'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    Contents: '**'

# working as intended
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  displayName: 'Use NuGet 6.8.0'

# working as intended
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'Restore NuGet Packages'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

# working as intended
- task: qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens@5
  displayName: 'Replace tokens in appsettings.json'
  inputs:
    targetFiles: '**/*.json'

# disabled task for testing
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution'
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
  enabled: false
    
# testing this task instead of VSBuild; in artifact there are tons of files, instead of one exe-file and one json-file
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Publish'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: false
    arguments: '-c $(buildConfiguration) -r $(runtimeId) --self-contained true --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: false
  enabled: true

# working as intended
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Test solution'
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

# working to publish it to SolutionDrop; not sure if this is all that needs to be done here
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: SolutionDrop'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    ArtifactName: SolutionDrop
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

The published artifact is >200 MB and has a ton of files. That can not be correct. Here you see just the top:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have received the result as it was intended to be.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71239913/20737189) was the final clue. And I did find the reference in Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/).

[image]

These properties are set in the project file:

```xml
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <IncludeAllContentForSelfExtract>true</IncludeAllContentForSelfExtract>
```

There was a [change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/sdk/8.0/runtimespecific-app-default) in the publish process by Microsoft. If PublishSingleFile is set to true, Self-Contained is implied automatically.
When the above properties are set in the project file, they do not need to be listed as arguments in the command line.

The ***DotNetCoreCLI@2*** task looks like this:

```yaml
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Publish *.csproj'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '**/DevOpsWpf.csproj'
    arguments: '-c Release -r win-x64 --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: false
```

The ***project file*** looks like this:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <IncludeAllContentForSelfExtract>true</IncludeAllContentForSelfExtract>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Mvvm" Version="8.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="8.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DevOpsWpf.Library\DevOpsWpf.Library.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="appsettings.Development.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <ExcludeFromSingleFile>True</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
    </None>
    <None Update="appsettings.Production.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Documentations\ReadMe.txt">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Properties\launchSettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  
</Project>
```